# TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py

This is my code for this command:

```
@client.command()
async def nitrosince(ctx, member: discord.Member, guild: discord.Guild = None):
  member = ctx.member if not member  else member
  guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild

  embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title="NitroSince Command",
        
    )

  embed.add_field(name=f"{member} Has had Nitro Since:", value = datetime.date.strftime(member.premium_since, '%a, %b %d %Y')

)
  embed.set_footer(text="I was made by Grenade Visuals#0001", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And whenever I run this code I get the error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object" Does anyone know why this is? And how I could possibly fix this?!

Comment: it means you try to do `datetime.date.strftime( None, ...)` and it means you have `None` in `member.premium_since`. So use `print( member.premium_since )` to check what you have. You can use `if/else` to skip it or send different message.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that `member.premium_since` is `None`, which is not a valid date.

You'll need to add code to support cases when that value is `None`, i.e. when someone is not premium.